# Value a column based on the value of another column in R

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` with a column that has values from 3 to 18. What I am trying to do is make a new column that is valued from 4 to 14. I want to roll my data up in the following way:

```
lace$New.Lace[lace$TOTAL.LACE == 3] <- 4
lace$New.Lace[lace$TOTAL.LACE >= 14] <- 13
```

I want to then make `lace$New.Lace` equal to `lace$TOTAL.LACE` when `lace$TOTAL.LACE > 4 && lace$TOTAL.LACE < 13] <- lace$TOTAL.LACE`

I tried doing the following:

```
lace$New.Lace[lace$TOTAL.LACE > 4 && lace$TOTAL.LACE < 13] <- lace$TOTAL.LACE
```

This ends up just making `lace$New.Lace` equal to `lace$TOTAL.LACE` so the vectors become identical.

How should I be writing this? I have already just written the instructions as:

```
lace$New.Lace[lace$TOTAL.LACE == 4] <- 4
lace$New.Lace[lace$TOTAL.LACE == 5] <- 5
...
```

Which is a pain in the butt.

Thank you,

Comment: use the `switch` function. look up `?switch()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can just iterate over TOTAL.Lace values and assign values to New.Lace based on your condition. Like in this example:

```
tl = 18:3
df = data.frame(tl)
df$nl = df$tl
for (i in 1:length(df$tl)) {
  if (df$tl[i] <= 4) {
    df$nl[i] = 4
  } else if (df$tl[i] >= 14) {
    df$nl[i] = 13
  }
}
```

I used your original condition:

```
lace$New.Lace[lace$TOTAL.LACE >= 14] <- 13
```

however it seems that it should be `<- 14`.